# Running awk script on local and remote files?

Tags: bash, awk

I have an awk script that runs on specific log files.  Initially we ran this on the machine that generates the log files so all was good, I just basically at the end of the script pointed to the local directory and file I need it to run on, for example:  /logs/logfile1

But now, I've added several other machines to help load balance our application, so each time a particular machine is accessed (in round robin fashion) that machine writes its own log file local to that machine.

How do I get the script to run on one machine but access the log files from all of the other machines as well?  (I could copy the script and run locally on each of the machines and append the outputs to one file as there are only 5 machines right now, but I figure there is an easier solution).

Also I run CentOS 6.x on these servers if that is helpful

EDIT:  I suppose I could create soft links to the other machines, on the machine that is running the script.  Just wondering if there is something easier?

Comment: On the central machine, NFS mount the directories from the remote machines that hold the logs.  Then access the remote logs via those directories.

Comment: You might want to invest in a centralized logging system. Some interesting reading: http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2012/01/03/centralized-logging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount the other machines file systems (via ssh, nfs, etc.) on the machine with the script.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting the required directories of all machines on one machine is probably the best solution. However, if you expect the number of machines to increase to a larger number in future, you should try for a scalable solution.
You could have a solution as below:

1. Maintain a file in one machine with a list of all other machines and their respective directories.
2. Have a script to telnet/ssh to each of those remote machines and execute your awk script.
3. Retrieve all the output files via ftp tom one machine and merge.